# Unecessary logs in headless testing using phantom js and selenium

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, phantomjs, headless

I am  getting so many unnecessary logs in red color while performing headless testing using `phantom js`.

How to remove all those red color logs
[image: red colour info messages]

```
public class Utility 
{
   private static WebDriver driver=new PhantomJSDriver();
   public static WebDriver getDriver() 
   {
      return driver;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what you need to do to suppress the INFO logs:

```
File src = new File("C:\\Utility\\phantomjs-2.1.1-windows\\bin\\phantomjs.exe");
System.setProperty("phantomjs.binary.path", src.getAbsolutePath());

DesiredCapabilities dcap = new DesiredCapabilities();
String[] phantomArgs = new  String[] {
    "--webdriver-loglevel=NONE"
};
dcap.setCapability(PhantomJSDriverService.PHANTOMJS_CLI_ARGS, phantomArgs);
PhantomJSDriver driver = new PhantomJSDriver(dcap);

driver.get("https://www.facebook.com/");
```

Let me know if it works for you.

Comment: My program doesnot have any main method. so it is throwing error. Where to write the code

Comment: @heardm you can use the code anywhere you wish. If you are using TestNG you can put the code within any method under Test or likewise Annotations. Raise a new question with your exact requirement I will be glad to help you out. Thanks